# Converting screen coordinates to page coordinates

Tags: javascript, html

Given the screen coordinates of a point, is there some way to calculate the coordinates of that point on the actual page of the browser?
[image: Here is a small image illustrating the problem]

Here is a small image illustrating the problem. I have a point(ScreenX,ScreenY) and want to convert it to point(PageX,PageY).

From what I have seen there is no way to calculate the height of the browser toolbar etc, so window.innerHeight and window.outerHeight do not really help here.

Anny help is appreciated :-)

Comment: How are you calculating the screenX and screenY

Comment: Through some external software

Answer (score 1):

```css
#div-id {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="div-id"> POSITION </div>

<script>
var element = document.getElementById('div-id');
var position = element.getBoundingClientRect();
var x = position.left;
var y = position.top;

var XLoc = window.screenX;
var YLoc = window.screenY;
var toolbarHeight = window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight;

console.log('Div position : X :',  x ,'--Y : ', y);


console.log('Window position: X:',  XLoc ,'-- Y : ', YLoc);

console.log('Actual position of DIV from scrren -  X:',  (x + XLoc) ,'-- Y : ', ( y + YLoc + toolbarHeight ) );

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

use below properties for the requirements.

`window.screenX`

`window.screenY`

Comment: Thanks, but window.screenX and window.screenY give the top left corner of the browser, but not the page. Therefore it does not work, as there is the menubar of the browser  :-/

Comment: so you can get the **height of the toolbar** that you can use in logic to get the output you want. use `window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight` to get the **height** includes `toolbar`, `address bar`, `tabs`

Comment: updated code with `toolbarHeight` so you will get actual `Y location` including toolbar height `(y + YLoc + toolbarHeight)`

Comment: Thank you - but that does not work either because of the debug window(console, inspector and all that stuff) that could  be open in the bottom of the browser :-/

Comment: What about windows taskbar? You assumed viewport touches the sides and bottom of the screen. The challenge here is to find viewport coordinates on screen.